# Confluent Kafka Elasticsearch. ClassCastException: TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have problem with publishing big json documents.
I have nested but correctly composed JSON (~1 mb)

when i'm publishing it, i'm getting exception from Confluent Elasticsearch connector:

```
connect_1    | [2018-08-14 11:42:57,532] ERROR Failed to execute batch 127 of 2 records (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor)
connect_1    | java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:70)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:34)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.execute(BulkProcessor.java:348)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:326)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:312)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
connect_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
connect_1    | [2018-08-14 11:42:57,537] ERROR Failed to execute batch 126 of 19 records (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor)
connect_1    | java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:70)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.BulkIndexingClient.execute(BulkIndexingClient.java:34)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.execute(BulkProcessor.java:348)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:326)
connect_1    |  at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:312)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
connect_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
connect_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and so on ...

from kafka and zookeeper i'm not getting any erros.

here is my setup:

Kafka

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers", ....);
props.put("acks",  "all");
props.put("linger.ms",   1);
props.put("buffer.memory",  33554432);
 props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
 props.put("value.serializer",  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Connect:

```
{
  "name": "test-connector-aaa",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "aaa",
    "topic.index.map": "aaa:test",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "false",
    "connection.url": "http://elastic:9200",
    "type.name": "Iata",
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
"read.timeout.ms": "6000",
"connection.timeout.ms": "5000"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be getting this error at present stacktrace.
I have mentioned connector code where exception is thrown. Please share kafka-connect-elasticsearch version

```
  final ObjectNode parsedError = (ObjectNode) OBJECT_MAPPER.readTree(item.error);
```

Comment: i'm using version 4.0.2 (i'm not using 5.0.0 because property topic.index.map was removed .... ). Still getting this error. java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode

Comment: please share you json data